Handle returning null from map method
I'm trying to handle a map method that get all my fields from a JSON query. Some of the fields I'm getting are empty which is fine, but when calling them I get an error saying "Cannot read properties of null".
So my idea was to put an if statement inside the map to check if the item is null and in that case don't return it at all. But I can't seem to get it to work and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.
This is how the code looks that doesn't work:
{
  peoplePosts.map((post) => (
    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
    <p>{post.content}</p>
    <p>{post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}</p>
  ))
}

Error message from this is: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'node')"
And this is my solution which doesn't work either 
{
  peoplePosts.map((post) => (
    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
    <p>{post.content}</p>
    if (post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl == null) {
      <p>Ouch</p>
    } else {
      <p>Yay</p>
    }
  ))
}

Error message from this is: "Expected ")" but found "if""

I would expect the "Cannot read properties of null" error to have something after it explaining which value is null, can you include the entire error message? (It's probably e.g. node or featuredImage that's null rather than the sourceUrl if your fix isn't working)

You say you can't get it to work, but what actually happens? Is there another error message? Does it just give a different result?

@DBS Added error messages now under the code examples :)

So, in the first snippet node is null, and in the second, you can't inline an if like that, you'd need to wrap it in {} and use a ternary operator (You'd also need to check node rather than node.sourceUrl). It's tough to give a proper answer without more context, but that should at least make it functional.

You need to use conditional (ternary) operators to render it properly
{
  peoplePosts.map((post) => (
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h2>{post.title}</h2>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      {post.featuredImage ? (
        <p>Yay</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Ouch</p>
      )}
    </div>
  ))
}


Thank you @pavlo-sobchuk That solves it. I also realized I could use Optional chaining as well, not sure what negatives that would imply though.
